# In-app billing - does marketplace keep pinging us until we confirmNotifications()?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm continuing on with the in-app billing sample provided by google, and I want to replace their Security class with an implementation on my server (as they recommend). Looks like I have to replace the following with a call to the implementation on my server:

```
/**
 * Verifies that the data was signed with the given signature, and calls
 * {@link ResponseHandler#purchaseResponse(Context, PurchaseState, String, String, long)}
 * for each verified purchase.
 * @param startId an identifier for the invocation instance of this service
 * @param signedData the signed JSON string (signed, not encrypted)
 * @param signature the signature for the data, signed with the private key
 */
private void purchaseStateChanged(int startId, String signedData, String signature) {
    // Instead of using the local version included on the client,
    // this should be an http call to our server which has the 
    // implementation.
    ArrayList<Security.VerifiedPurchase> purchases;
    purchases = Security.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
    if (purchases == null) {
        return;
    }


    // Then the rest gets executed after the http response comes back.
    ...

    confirmNotifications(startId, notifyIds);
```

So I'd replace the above and when I get a response from my server, I'd run the confirmNotifications() bit etc. But there are lots of things that can go wrong here, the network could drop out etc. So I assume the marketplace will keep sending me messages until I successfully do the confirmNotifications() bit?

Slightly terrified that something goes awry when I start verifying on my server, and I get a bunch of users whose credit cards have been charged, but don't see the content showing up on their device.

Also, I think the thread of piracy is quite low for my app, but I'm concerned about leaving my marketplace public key embedded in the client. If I do have a popular title some day in the future, attackers could look to some older apps from me and get it out of them (not sure how much of a danger it is if they get the public key).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes the market will continue sending notification for the events you have never submitted a confirm Notification, as the doc says:

> CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS:
>   This request acknowledges that your application received the details of a purchase state change. Google Play sends purchase state change notifications to your application until you confirm that you received them.

look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html)

Comment: In what intervals are they being sent? And for how long? If I never confirm, will I be receiving spam till very death?

Comment: Well it is difficult to say. As far as I remember the market sends a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS every time you connect to the market service.